# Frequency Range VI(Labview)

Tags: rf, impedance, communication, labview

[image: article: impedance measurument]
I tried to understand what "Frequency range vi" consists. But I didn't understand.

From Reference Article(doi:10.15199/48.2021.11.10): No.1 shows the block diagrams of fixed-point data consisting of the start frequency, the end frequency, and the step frequency to set the frequency range and the number of working loops. The number of frequencies in the range and working loops were determined by subtracting the end frequency from the start frequency, then dividing the difference by the step frequency. All the frequencies were defined and kept in an array.

Comment: That block is going to do one of two operations: generate logrithmically spaced, or linearly spaced frequencies. Check the source code for Numpy for a python example of what the operation is. Linear: https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/8cec82012694571156e8d7696307c848a7603b4e/numpy/core/function_base.py#L24 Logrithmic: https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/8cec82012694571156e8d7696307c848a7603b4e/numpy/core/function_base.py#L190

Comment: @pgvoorhees Thanks for responding but I am working on Labview.

Comment: Yes, I understand that. That VI you are pointing to is one the researchers wrote and they are the only ones that can tell you, for sure, what is in the VI. What I am suggesting is you look at the PYTHON code in order to understand what the VI is doing. The python code will do roughly the same tasks as the VI, but the source is available for you to look at.